# Can SaaS and PaaS be used together?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

PaaS is used for creating custom applications using programming which will later be deployed onto the provider's cloud.

SaaS, on the other hand, the consumer uses the provider's applications running on the provider's infrastructure. Also, SaaS uses PaaS

Can the provider and the consumer be the same thing?

If a certain organisation uses SaaS can it go back to PaaS and build an application that it needs and then use it on SaaS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. SaaS - You build an application (e.g. App_A), deploy it somewhere (cloud) and different customers use the application over the web or without having to host it themselves.
2. When you build the application, (e.g. App_A) and have to deploy it to a cloud provider, you have 2 options

   a) Take care of 'virtually' building the hardware - you select disk size, select an OS, memory size, install all the necessary software and then you deploy your application on it. In this case, you are using an Infrastructure as a Service (IaaS). It's like building a computer first and then installing (deploying) your App.

   b) Second option is that the cloud provider handles all of the earlier mentioned components and you just deploy your code. It's like someone gives you an already built computer and you just install your code (your application). This is Platform as a service (PaaS)

At the end of the day, you can run a business (a SaaS) on a PaaS e.g. Khan Academy & SnapChat both run on Google App Engine. In these examples, Khan Academy and SnapChat are both SaaS running on Google App Engine which is a PaaS

Answer (score 0):

> Can the provider and the consumer be the same thing?

I think you are confusing these two terms. The *provider* is the CSP (cloud service provider) and *consumer* is the entity/users actually accessing the software/infrastructure.

The whole point of PAAS is that it provides a framework for developers to build customized applications, as well as simple cost-effective deployment of apps. If you wanted to access your application through the cloud similar to how SAAS works then that is entirely possible but would still require you pay the CSP for VM space to run your applications